# Something deletes my cookies

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I can’t find what deletes my cookies. I use AngularJS and $cookie.putObject with the only option 'expires':

```
var now = new Date();
$cookies.putObject(
    'myArray',
    this. myArray,
    {expires: new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+6, now.getDate())}
);
```

After that I can see my cookie in the browser with a proper expiring. However, when I restart Chrome, there's no the cookie. When I restart Firefox, cookie is available, however disappears when I open the page where the cookie was created.
Who can tell me what's going on?

Comment: It might be a setting in chrome itself. I know that you can specify in Chrome to ignore the Session flag on a cookie and keep it forever (a remember me function in the browser). The opposite might be true as well, that cookies are always deleted even when there is a set expiration date. Try it in FireFox or IE to test if its a `Chrome feature` or something specific with your code.

Comment: Thaks. I've tried it in Forefox as I mentioned. And also I have no any issues with other sites. I think, something is wrong with AngularJS and unfortunately there's a lack of documentation.

Comment: My bad, I missed Firefox in there. Have you looked at this setting for Chrome [Google Chrome deletes cookies automatically ](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/EEYePxoNcAc)? If that works then its a setting you can do little about I think. As for FireFox, maybe there is a setting there too somewhere or maybe the script re-inits the cookie (not sure what the rest of the code looks like).

Comment: Yes, I’ve checked it. There's everything is alright regarding to these Chrome settings. Btw, I've moved my App from the local environment to the web, and now cookies are being deleting on page refresh. I think the cause of problem somewhere in AngularJS.

Comment: @zhekaus Did you ever get it sorted out ?

Comment: I did. However, I don't remember how and I moved to Angular 2+ (5) year ago. I have such a problem now.